# How is data copied to HDFS when there's multiple dfs.data.dir

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

`dfs.data.dir` allows more than one directory for datanode to store data blocks. When data is copied to the HDFS, how is the data distributed across the directories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `dfs.data.dir` has multiple values, data is copied to the HDFS in a round-robin fashion. If one of the directory's disk is full, round-robin data copy will continue on the rest of the directories.